# Set position of jquery draggable element while dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable

In my web app, there is a draggable element.
I need to set the left position of this element when the element reaches a certain limit while dragging.
Using jQuery draggable widget, I have access to the position of the element:

```
function drag(e, ui) {
 console.log(ui.position.left);
}
```

Let say my left attribute is setted to 1100px, I need to set it to 500px and this, without stopping the dragging.

I have three functions: dragStart, drag, and gradEnd. 
Currently, I managed to get only one result: when setting `ui.position.left = 500;` on the drag function (using a condition), the left position is set to 500 but of course, the element is then stuck at 500px. The reason is that every time the drag function is triggered, the left position is setted to 500.

If the code runs only once the line `ui.position.left = 500;` the position left attribute is set to 500, but directly reset to 1100.

How can I set the left attribute once and for all?

```js
$("#divId").draggable({
  drag: drag,
})

function drag(e, ui) {
  if (ui.position.top > 50) {
    ui.position.left = 100;
  }
}
```

```css
#divId {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="divId">
  Bubble
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sam101CS/nx4ka70u/16/

Comment: I want the left position to increase during the dragging.

Comment: But it does increase, though - or am I missing something?

Comment: It does increase but then when coming back to the top of the screen, it does decrease too, and that’s not the behavior that I want to implement. I want to increase the left position once for all.

Comment: Yes, but only after that one condition is set to true, and this without stopping the dragging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how `jQuery Draggable` handles things under the hood, but even after setting `ui.position.left = 100`, it does not register in the event until after dragging has stopped - that is why I opted to check the actual `CSS` property of the element that is being targeted.

I have also provided an example (closure/functional based) which demonstrates how to handle this without having to check `CSS`..

---

---

***First example:***

```js
$("#divId").draggable({
  drag: drag
});

function drag(e, ui) {
  if (ui.position.top > 50) {
    $("#container").css('padding-left', '100px');
    $(this).css('left', '0px');
  }
  if (ui.position.left < 0) {
    ui.position.left = 0
  }
}
```

```css
#divId {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: grab;
}

#container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="divId">
    Bubble
  </div>
</div>
```

---

---

---

***Second example, more of a 'closure based functional approach':*** does not require you to check `CSS`..

```js
$("#divId").draggable({
  drag: drag()
});

function drag(e, ui) {
  let TRIGGER = false, TOP_THRESHOLD = 50, LEFT_POSITION = 100;
  return function(e, ui) {
    if (TRIGGER) {
      ui.position.left = LEFT_POSITION;
    } else if (ui.position.top > TOP_THRESHOLD) {
      TRIGGER = true;
      ui.position.left = LEFT_POSITION;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#divId {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid #000000;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  cursor: grab;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="divId">
  Bubble
</div>
```

---

---

Comment: The problem here is once the left position increased, the element can't be dragged on the x-axis...

Comment: Maybe there is a way to end the dragging and restart it immediately to register the event?